# A PHP function to get pdf from the db and display on-screen

Tags: php, pdf

Please I've been searching for a method of fetching pdf from the database and displaying in an  or  tag with its name and other fields. But when on a PHP page the pdf does not show on-screen.
And when I do the the fetch and echo on the tag the page does not display the pdf. It says

> Forbidden. You don't have permission to access this resource.
> The Pdf is stored in the data base as a file location. And I want to fetch and display it on a PHP page

Comment: Welcome, to improve your experience on SO please [take the tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) 
and read [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), an [On Topic question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), 
then look at the [Question Check list](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648/stack-overflow-question-checklist), 
the [perfect question](http://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/) and 
how to create a [Minimal, Complete and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: 1) We would need to know exactly what you mean by ___fetching pdf from the database ___ Is it stored on the DB as a file or is just the file location stored on the database

Comment: 2) Do you want to show the PDF on the page, or download the PDF to the users PC

Comment: 3) The message **Forbidden. You don't have permission to access this resource.** Normally means a mis-configured Web Server.

Comment: It is stored in the db as a file location. So I want to display it on the php page

Comment: There must be hundereds of tutorial examples out there on the web for this.

Comment: I tried most of them but I'm not able to get the result I want that's why I posted this problem